# Finding the mean of selected variables in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to build a table that summarizes the median of each isoform (ADA1, ADA2, and Total ADA) per each of the four visits, totalling at least 12 medians. I'm struggling to put the select and median functions together without error. I'm also unsure whether I accidentally lost all of the Visit 1 variables during my manipulations of the dataframe. Will someone please help me check that Visit 1 variables still exist, and then create a table listing all of the medians?

[image]

Comment: Could you post your select and median functions that are failed?

Comment: The title of your post says "Finding the mean" whereas your question says "summarizes the median". Which one is correct?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I meant "median", not "mean"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with sample data, somewhat similar to your picture.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
dat <- tibble(
  Vaccine = sample(c("HBV", "BCG"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
  isoform = sample(c("ADA1", "ADA2", "Total ADA"), size=100, replace=TRUE),
  fc = rexp(100), `log(fc)` = log1p(fc))
dat
# # A tibble: 100 x 4
#    Vaccine isoform       fc `log(fc)`
#    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1 HBV     ADA2      1.10      0.741 
#  2 HBV     ADA1      1.66      0.978 
#  3 HBV     ADA2      0.910     0.647 
#  4 HBV     ADA1      3.59      1.52  
#  5 BCG     ADA2      0.0600    0.0583
#  6 BCG     Total ADA 1.38      0.867 
#  7 BCG     ADA1      2.16      1.15  
#  8 BCG     ADA1      0.123     0.116 
#  9 HBV     Total ADA 2.21      1.17  
# 10 BCG     ADA2      2.08      1.12  
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

We can simply group and summarize with:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(Vaccine, isoform) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(fc, "log(fc)"), list(mu = ~ mean(.), median = ~ median(.))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Vaccine isoform   fc_mu `log(fc)_mu` fc_median `log(fc)_median`
#   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1 BCG     ADA1      0.970        0.571     0.590            0.459
# 2 BCG     ADA2      1.44         0.795     1.13             0.757
# 3 BCG     Total ADA 1.22         0.731     1.27             0.819
# 4 HBV     ADA1      1.26         0.739     0.964            0.674
# 5 HBV     ADA2      1.56         0.798     1.10             0.741
# 6 HBV     Total ADA 0.876        0.582     0.787            0.581
```

If you want base R,

```r
aggregate(cbind(fc, `log(fc)`) ~ Vaccine + isoform, data = dat,
          FUN = function(z) c(mu=mean(z), med=median(z)))
#   Vaccine   isoform     fc.mu    fc.med log(fc).mu log(fc).med
# 1     BCG      ADA1 0.9704116 0.5899109  0.5714296   0.4594965
# 2     HBV      ADA1 1.2644729 0.9636581  0.7386704   0.6740528
# 3     BCG      ADA2 1.4422983 1.1322882  0.7949414   0.7571957
# 4     HBV      ADA2 1.5551761 1.0975749  0.7977444   0.7407819
# 5     BCG Total ADA 1.2164525 1.2682549  0.7308947   0.8190108
# 6     HBV Total ADA 0.8756976 0.7872367  0.5820488   0.5806707
```

or with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[
  , unlist(lapply(.SD, function(z) list(mu=mean(z), med=median(z))),
          recursive = FALSE),
    by = .(Vaccine, isoform), .SDcols = c("fc", "log(fc)")][]
#    Vaccine   isoform     fc.mu    fc.med log(fc).mu log(fc).med
# 1:     HBV      ADA2 1.5551761 1.0975749  0.7977444   0.7407819
# 2:     HBV      ADA1 1.2644729 0.9636581  0.7386704   0.6740528
# 3:     BCG      ADA2 1.4422983 1.1322882  0.7949414   0.7571957
# 4:     BCG Total ADA 1.2164525 1.2682549  0.7308947   0.8190108
# 5:     BCG      ADA1 0.9704116 0.5899109  0.5714296   0.4594965
# 6:     HBV Total ADA 0.8756976 0.7872367  0.5820488   0.5806707
```

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! I'm still new to Stack Overflow and to R, so I apologize for my messups. Anyhow, I really appreciate the help :)